# Building a thermostat ui , overlapping two elements , but cant access the slider element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, round-slider

I'm building a thermostat ui based on nest, so I designed a circle with a shadow and the temperature in the middle and then added a second element, a round slider based on http://roundsliderui.com/. However when I use the z-index to overlap the elements, I have to put the slider below the circle and somehow can't access the slider after that.

[image]

Comment: Yess, it was indeed a duplicate and i managed to get it to work. Thank you so much. I have been trying to get this to work all day!!

Comment: have you solved your reported issue? I hope you can achieve your requirement with roundSlider tooltip itself, so you don't need of additional circle element (which won't create these problems). Check the below demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/jwjwrLw7/